# Excel Formula Shows Zeros Instead Of Blanks

Tags: excel

I have some code for copying large amounts of data from a sheet in one file to a sheet in another. It does almost everything I want, except when the cell being copied is blank, it inputs a 0. I'd like it to remain blank.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!A$2:A$15000)=A120945)*('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!L$2:L$15000=M120945),),0)),"",INDEX('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!AB$2:AB$15000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!A$2:A$15000)=A120945)*('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!L$2:L$15000=M120945),),0)))
```

The code basically looks at the date and name in source and target and if they match, it then copies the contents of whichever cell I choose (row AB on this occasion) into the target sheet. The downside is when the source cell is blank, it puts a zero in the target file instead of leaving it blank. I tried changing the 0 which occurs in the code twice to a blank, but no result. it still remained a 0 in the target.

Comment: There are two ways to approach this: You could replace the `0` at the very end of your code with an empty string `""`. This will lead to problems if calculations are being performed on the cells however. You could also simply hide zero values as is described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03). [Here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/pro-tip-three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/) are some additional ways to hide zero values in a worksheet.

Comment: As I can't edit my above comment anymore, I would like to add this correction: Replacing the `0` with `""` in the formula did not lead to errors when performing calculations like `SUM` or `AVERAGE` on the cell, so that is probably the most straightforward solution.

Comment: Hi M.Schalk
Unfortunately replacing just the last zero with "" gives #VALUE! as a result. There are no further calculation which will happen, in fact, once all the data is transferred, I do a copy and paste special, just pasting values, so the sheet now simple has the results with no formulas. 
I also don't wish to simply hide any zero values, as if a cell in the source has a zero, I wish that reflected. A zero is different to a blank and I am simply after the target cell to reflect exactly what is in the source cell.
cheers

Comment: Have you tried with a Macro or VBA function instead?

Comment: No Biggum I haven't. I have a formula which allows me to transfer upwards of 120,000 rows of data a row at a time and it works well, other than the fact it changes blanks into zeros. Apart from that, the rest is fine, so do not wish to head to another route. There will be a way to have it do what I wish; just not obvious at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Just replace de zero at the end of your formula with "" to show a blank cell

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!A$2:A$15000)=A120945)*('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!L$2:L$15000=M120945),),0)),"",INDEX('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!AB$2:AB$15000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!A$2:A$15000)=A120945)*('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!L$2:L$15000=M120945),),"")))
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Problem is Biggum, that puts #VALUE! as the result. If I also do the earlier zero to "", it puts a blank in ALL cells, not just the ones with a zero, so still no closer. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer

Comment: This does not work as the last `0` is the last argument for a `MATCH` function.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I could'nt test it. I have not sample files.
Can you post sample values instead of references?

Comment: cheers Biggum. Not sure how to post what you ask for so that it is legible on this forum

Comment: Don't worry.
Maybe nesting your function into another IF which evaluates first, for your condition of "".
=IF(Origin CELL = ""; Destiny CELL = ""; Your_Function);
Try first to evaluate escape cases

Comment: Not sure how this can be done as the origin cell is looked up and matched in the subsequent formula, matching date and name in the source with date and name in the target. So there is no way to determine the origin cell without that following code. I cannot simply type a cell location. 
Any idea of how to add the check you are referring to into the formula I have? Cheers

Comment: The idea is the same as in my answer: Check if the result evaluates to 0, if yes replace it with "". If no, just keep the result.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you are looking for:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!A$2:A$15000)=A120945)*('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!L$2:L$15000=M120945),),0)),"",IF(INDEX('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!AB$2:AB$15000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!A$2:A$15000)=A120945)*('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!L$2:L$15000=M120945),),0))=0;"";INDEX('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!AB$2:AB$15000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!A$2:A$15000)=A120945)*('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/Research/Master Data File/2017/Additional/New Algorithm/[December.csv]December'!L$2:L$15000=M120945),),0))))
```

I do have to admit that this is not an elegant solution though.

Comment: Cheers M.Schalk, but that does not pass muster. Excel immediately indicates a problem with the formula. Thanks

Comment: What kind of problem? Does it let you enter the formula that way at all? Or does it show a reult error like `#NV`?

Comment: If I input that code exactly as is, it goes in fine, but as soon as I change the row to the row I am in, an error message pops up. The row in the code above is 120945 and I changed all of those references to 3, which is the row I want to put the result in. The message immediately pops up and is the standard box with "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character........"
So it's odd that the formula copies straight in OK, but when I alter the row reference, it fails

Comment: That sounds weird, changing 120945 to 3 should not have an effect on whether the formula works or not. Are you sure you entered everything correctly without deleting something etc..?

Comment: copy and paste, so yes, it goes in as a copy and paste fine, though with no result. The code just sits there still showing as code in the cell. So copy and paste the cell just sits there and then any changes and an error

Comment: Just so you know, even if I don't change the row, but rather change the filename to January, the same error message comes up, but the original code you supplied just sits in the cell as code, no result shows up.

Comment: I'm not sure I've experienced the behavior you're describing, would you be able to share a screenshot?

Comment: OK, so just tried something. I copied all of the code firstly into a text editor and made the changes there, changing 120945 to 3 and changing December to January. I copied it into the cell and it gave an error message, but this time highlighted the first "" marks. I deleted and retyped them and it then showed the 0 as the problem. This zero, the one after the = it highlights as the issue L$2:L$15000=M120945),),0))=0;"";INDEX('/Users/SOS

Comment: I am using this exact formula with different references and it works fine for me, please provide a scrrenshot of what you're seeing. Otherwise I will not be able to provide additional help.

Comment: M.Schalk. I uploaded a screenshot to imguy, https://imgur.com/a/ldyWhRb
So if I copy and paste your copy without making any changes and hit enter, the code just sits there in the cell; no result appears at all

Comment: Could it possibly be something in your additional code around the numbers or rows? You can see that the number of rows in the standard code is set to 15000. That works fine for me as all of the source files are less. But the target file has over 120,000 rows. I don't know what your code is actually asking, but in a nutshell, my original code asks this and let's use row 2; IF A2 (SOURCE) = A2 (TARGET) AND L2 (SOURCE) = M2 (TARGET), THEN RESULT IS THE CONTENTS OF AB2. The additional should be only IF AB2 IS 0, THEN 0, IF AB2 IS BLANK THEN NOTHING. The additional syntax simply does not work

Comment: Oh, forgot to add that date, which in A, is a different format in the source than in the target, thus the use of INT. Source has date and time in a single cell, whereas target has date in A and time in B. Not sure if that assists at all

Comment: Is there nobody with any suggestions on a solution to this, as so far, I am stuck with my original code which, whilst it transfers all of the data, turns blanks into zeros? To date, no working solution has been offered, though I appreciate the input.